# How do I imitate the ASP.NET AjaxOptions delegate functions?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-ajax

When using the `Ajax.BeginForm()` helper in `ASP.Net MVC`, I can pass options with names of different functions, for example one to run `OnBegin`, one for `OnSuccess` etc. How do these work "under the hood"?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm extending this to provide a `JQuery` based alternative, and I need to figure out how to get from having the method names specified in a `JSON` string to actually calling them.

The `AjaxOptions` class has a method for serializing, in which it wraps the method name in the following way (in this example, the `AjaxOptions` `OnSuccess` property is set to `mySuccessFunction(p)`:

```
onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, mySuccessFunction(p))
```

I have produced my own `JQueryAjaxOptions` class, which serializes in the same way (but with some extra options available). So asically, what I have available in my method for posting the form is the above property as part of a json object, and I need to be able to call the function.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem:

What it really boiled down to, was executing a line of code contained in a string variable. This can easily be done using the 'eval(x)' syntax. The following example works for the onSuccess property:

```
eval(settings.onSuccess)
```

Sometimes you just need to think one more step backwards to realize what you're trying to do, and how easy it is =)